# What does the Jamie Zawinski's quotation about regular expressions mean?

Tags: quotations, regular-expressions

In [a message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.emacs.xemacs/CyHb8HW-hKs/n1WCMEw5iCkJ) to comp.emacs.xemacs, [Jamie Zawinski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) once said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

I've always had trouble understanding what he was getting at. What does he mean by this?

**Update**

The answer that I'm looking for is one which explains what the 2nd problem is. Most answers below are that regexes are hard, which doesn't seem to fit the question.